# How to set ID header in Spring Integration Kafka Message?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I have a demo Spring Integration project which is receiving Kafka messages, aggregating them, and then releasing them. I'm trying to add `JdbcMessageStore` to the project. The problem is that it failing with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot store messages without an ID header
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore.addMessage(JdbcMessageStore.java:314) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-5.3.8.RELEASE.jar:5.3.8.RELEASE]
```

After debugging I found that it requires the UUID header `id` in this message. But the problem is that I can't manually set the Kafka header id - it is forbidden (the same as `timestamp` header) - I tried to do this in Kafka producer in different project.

If I'm using IDEA plugin named `Big Data Tools` and send a message from there I'm able to set `id` header but it is received by my project as an array of bytes and it is failing with error

```
IllegalArgumentException Incorrect type specified for header 'id'. Expected [UUID] but actual type is [B]
```

I can't find any solution on how to resolve this issue. I need to set somehow this `id` header to be able to store messages in the database.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` has an option:

```
/**
 * Set the message converter to use with a record-based consumer.
 * @param messageConverter the converter.
 */
public void setRecordMessageConverter(RecordMessageConverter messageConverter) {
```

Where you can set a `MessagingMessageConverter` with:

```
/**
 * Generate {@link Message} {@code ids} for produced messages. If set to {@code false},
 * will try to use a default value. By default set to {@code false}.
 * @param generateMessageId true if a message id should be generated
 */
public void setGenerateMessageId(boolean generateMessageId) {
    this.generateMessageId = generateMessageId;
}

/**
 * Generate {@code timestamp} for produced messages. If set to {@code false}, -1 is
 * used instead. By default set to {@code false}.
 * @param generateTimestamp true if a timestamp should be generated
 */
public void setGenerateTimestamp(boolean generateTimestamp) {
    this.generateTimestamp = generateTimestamp;
}
```

set to `true`.

This way the `Message` created from a `ConsumerRecord` will have respective `id` and `timestamp` headers.

You also simply can have a "dummy" transformer to return incoming payload and the framework will create a new `Message` where those headers are generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me a tip on the following issue: I store messages and groups and db, but the application restarted before GroupTimeout expires. And I need to send messages that stuck in DB when application starts

Comment: This deserves its own SO question, please

Comment: I have created separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76385338/how-to-send-messages-after-spring-integration-application-restarted Thank you in advance