# How to send Messages after Spring Integration application restarted?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a small Spring Integration application, I'm storing messages and messaging groups in the database. Currently, I have a case when some messages/groups are waiting to be sent after group timeout, but the application restarted. And when the application started I still have messages in DB and they won't be sent. I need some configuration to send expired message group from DB or resume timer. I tried to use reaper, but it does not work as expected. My code is:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumingChannelConfig {

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel consumingChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
        KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter =
                new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(kafkaListenerContainer());
        kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(consumingChannel());
        MessagingMessageConverter messageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setGenerateMessageId(true);
        kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setRecordMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return ...;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMessageStore jdbcMessageStore() {
        return new JdbcMessageStore(getDataSource());
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "consumingChannel")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler aggregator() {
        long timeout = 10000L;
        AggregatingMessageHandler aggregator =
                new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(),
                        jdbcMessageStore());
        aggregator.setOutputChannel((message, l) -> {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + message);
            return true;
        });
        aggregator.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(timeout));
//        aggregator.setTaskScheduler(this.taskScheduler);
        aggregator.setCorrelationStrategy(new MyCorrelationStrategy());
        aggregator.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
        aggregator.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
        aggregator.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
        aggregator.setDiscardChannel((message, timeout1) -> {
            System.out.println("DISCARD: " + message + ", timeout: " + timeout1);
            return true;
        });
        aggregator.setReleaseStrategy(new ReleaseStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean canRelease(MessageGroup group) {
                return System.currentTimeMillis() - group.getTimestamp() >= timeout;
            }
        });
        return aggregator;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageGroupStoreReaper reaper() {
        MessageGroupStoreReaper reaper = new MessageGroupStoreReaper(jdbcMessageStore());
        reaper.setPhase(1);
        reaper.setTimeout(2000L);
        reaper.setAutoStartup(true);
//        reaper.setExpireOnDestroy(true);
        return reaper;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaListenerContainer() {
        ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("spring-integration-topic");

        return new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
                consumerFactory(), containerProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "spring-integration");
        // automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
//        DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**UPD: My Solution**

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringIntegrationExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationExampleApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Autowired
    private MessageGroupStoreReaper reaper;

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 2000, fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE)
    public void start() {
        reaper.run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageGroupStoreReaper` doesn't work by itself, it has to be called from a `@Scheduled` method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#reaper

However there is a nice option for you from an aggregator perspective:

```
/**
 * Perform a {@link MessageGroupStore#expireMessageGroups(long)} with the provided {@link #expireTimeout}.
 * Can be called externally at any time.
 * Internally it is called from the scheduled task with the configured {@link #expireDuration}.
 * @since 5.4
 */
public void purgeOrphanedGroups() {
```

You just need to set that `expireTimeout > 0`:

```
/**
 * Configure a timeout in milliseconds for purging old orphaned groups from the store.
 * Used on startup and when an {@link #expireDuration} is provided, the task for running
 * {@link #purgeOrphanedGroups()} is scheduled with that period.
 * The {@link #forceReleaseProcessor} is used to process those expired groups according
 * the "force complete" options. A group can be orphaned if a persistent message group
 * store is used and no new messages arrive for that group after a restart.
 * @param expireTimeout the number of milliseconds to determine old orphaned groups in the store to purge.
 * @since 5.4
 * @see #purgeOrphanedGroups()
 */
public void setExpireTimeout(long expireTimeout) {
```

See also docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator-xml

> Starting with version 5.4, the aggregator (and resequencer) can be configured to expire orphaned groups (groups in a persistent message store that might not otherwise be released).

Comment: hmm.. I was not able to find those methods, maybe because I'm not using the latest  version. I found solution and updated my question. Anyway, thank you for ideas

Comment: Right, `@Scheduled` was one of my suggestion you have missed in your original question. It is really better to always to try keeping your projects up to date with dependencies: we may already have some solution and many fixes in newer versions.

Comment: It would be great to see in next releases this feature in more handy way

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: there is that `MessageGroupStoreReaper` and it can be used with a `@Scheduled`. There is also that `purgeOrphanedGroups()`. What else do you think is need to be done in the framework in this area?

Comment: I think it's better to have some flag like `aggregator.releaseMessagesOnStartup(true)`

Comment: Why is that? See that `setExpireTimeout()` Javadoc. The group release process is more complicated that you think: it is called "released" (or complete) only when respective `ReleaseStrategy` answers `true` for us. Otherwise it is called "expire", while it doesn't mean that group will be discarded. It simply can be released partially. Plus there is no need to release all the groups since you may send new messages into them after application restart. Therefore those groups will be released naturally like it would felt for you without app restarts.

Comment: That's exactly why we went with an `expireTimeout` logic: to `purgeOrphanedGroups` only if they are stuck in the store for a while, not because we just restart. What if with your `releaseMessagesOnStartup(true)` we would clean up the whole store, but then a new message arrives for a group to release it naturally? It would be not consistent according the grouping expectations. Therefore your suggestion is proven to be erroneous and it is better to make yourself familiar with that `expireTimeout` and `purgeOrphanedGroups` combination to make your solution as robust as possible.